# Pro's and con's of website built through MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Currently i am wondering whether or not to use a MySQL DB to provide content on my website.

An example of what i mean is based loosely here: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/

find the sample called SEO. Alternatively [Click Here](http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/)

Anyone with HTML5 able browsers will notice the URL is 'pretty' and is what you'd expect to find on any standard website.

Anyone with IE8 or a browser which isnt 'Webkit' enabled, will see the use of the Hashbang (`#!`) in order for SEO.

The problem is this: the content is pulled from a MySQL DB.. 
I have approx 30 pages (some are PACKED with content) And im wondering if all this tedious modification of my website is necessary?

I use jQuery MySQL and PHP through a single page interface so my content is not indexable at all. What are your views?

Help me!!

PS. would it be easier to provide PHP Includes in my DB content to fetch pages without having to upload all my pages into my DB?

Comment: Sounds like you should just install Wordpress

Comment: nooo, wordpress is not what i seek to achieve. i build the pages how i want them, not around a template :)

Comment: Mysql has nothing to do with urls and SEO. So, your question makes no sense.

Comment: I must admit I'm thoroughly confused: are you asking 1) how to make a site indexable? 2) whether to use MySQL to store page data? 3) whether to use AJAX? 4) how to achieve cross-browser compatibility? You seem to be asking bits of each, but not really anything in total.

Comment: what? Have you guys looked at the links to the examples? Dont you understand whats happening?? @piskvor - question 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question is made up of a lot of questions. :)

to mysql or not to mysql: most of the PHP-usng web world is using mysql as a database to store content. i don't see much of a problem there. 30 pages is peanuts.

jquery and php for a single page interface indexable: depends on the search engine. i've read somewhere (too lazy to look things up) that google uses a javascript enabled crawler. not sure if they use it in production already.

PHP includes in DB content: textpattern uses this approach. your worry is a problem of scale.

if your PHP code can serve pages properly, it wouldn't matter where it pulls content from. DB or filesystem wouldn't matter at this point.

just do it.

Comment: any ideas why i cant parse any code (HTML,PHP) through MySQL? for some reason i can only display text..

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - if you were able to lend a hand maybe suggesting the `eval()` function would help me..

Comment: @Ricki I'd cut my hand off if it give you such "help"

Answer (score 3):

## There is no such question.

Mysql is okay.
Its general purpose solution for storing site data, everyone using it with not a single problem and even Wikipedia is happy with it.

Mysql is irrelevant to any problems of your site.

Your problem is somewhere else but you forgot to state it. Let me suggest you to ask another question, pointing to the real problem you have, not some guess you made of it's reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can avoid it, avoir storing pages inside MySQL, unless you want to give the administrator the possibility to edit the pages.

Aside from that, there is no problem in storing pages in a DB, would it be MySQL or others. A lot of CMS do it (Drupal, Joomla, etc.).

You might encounter some performance issues on your DB server if your traffic becomes high, but this is another problem.

Comment: so maybe an include via php would be a better idea? i dont fancy having to make adjustments to my site via phpmyadmin. thanks

Comment: What you'd want to do, Ricki, is code a page/content/template editor, like what WordPress or other CMS systems have, so you don't have to go through SQL to edit them.  The simplest form of which would just be a (admin login protected) form with a text box that pulls in the raw HTML from the database and allows editing and saving.  A more complex form would be something like implementing TinyMCE.

Comment: i will look into TinyMCE. but your idea is a great one. never thought of it like that!

Answer (score 1):

In my tests and comparison, mysql connectivity and queries do slow down responses. If your site is simple and you are only doing updates yourself, then using a template engine and storing content in a files is not a bad choice.

If you decide to put it into SQL, then eventually you might need to build a cache. Hopefully nginx and not the php cache, so it shouldn't be a problem too.

The deciding factor is how you are willing to edit the content. I found that myself and my team is much more comfortable with editing html files through notepad++, Vim or Coda. If content is inside a database you get a poorly-performing (compared to desktop app) WYSIWYG editor.

Always use SQL the content is generated by your users. And do use some lightweight CMS.

I am using the one bundled with [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) myself and templates look like this:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-web/tree/master/templates/jui

Comment: thanks for the reply. i'd be editing the files/pages myself and prefer good old notepad++. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

> would it be easier to provide PHP Includes in my DB content

I think you'll find your site far easier to maintain for years IF you keep a very clear separation of duties: data goes in a database, presentation and code go in files.

While there is some contention whether it is a good idea to store *templates* in a database, my gut feeling says that you should avoid that temptation unless you have a very good reason.

But storing *code* (your PHP `include` statements) in the database is almost certainly not the best way forward.